# I don't understand a Shell Sciprt that I refer to

Tags: bc

There is a shell script to check if CPU usage exceeds CPU threshold,

But one thing that I don't understand is in Below script, why 1 is there ?

```
COMPARE='echo "if ($CPU_Usage>=$CPU_Threshold) 1" | bc'
```

Does a script mean if CPU Usage >= CPU_Threshold, then COMPARE variable set to 1 ?

And if not COMPARE variable set to 0 ?

Comment: Try it interactively from the shell.  Set different values of `$CPU_Usage` and `$CPU_Threshold` and observe how `$COMPARE` changes.